# Best tool for synchronizing MySQL databases

Tags: mysql, synchronization

I'm on a little quest of merging the structure of two MySql databases. Is there a tool for this with the might of Red-Gate's SQL Compare? Are there any free alternatives?

Comment: Maybe a little late for you... but Red Gate has recently released MySQL Compare, which is the MySQL equivalent to SQL Compare. http://mysql-compare.com/

Comment: Shouldn't this go to dba.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: Or http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

I've been using [SQLyog](https://webyog.com/) for years now. Recently they released v8.0 which includes an updated interface and two very cool features the Query Profiler and SQL Formatter. The formatter was the reason I upgraded this year.

[http://www.webyog.com/en/sqlyog_feature_list.php](https://web.archive.org/web/20120922005500/http://www.webyog.com:80/en/sqlyog_feature_list.php)

Blog post with video and animated gif of the SQL Formatter in action
[http://www.webyog.com/blog/2009/02/02/profile-and-format-mysql-queries-with-the-new-sqlyog-80/](https://web.archive.org/web/20120822052946/http://www.webyog.com:80/blog/2009/02/02/profile-and-format-mysql-queries-with-the-new-sqlyog-80/)

A few years ago I tried Navicat and the mysql manager but decided on SQLyog. I'm sure both products have been updated since but I'm still happy with SQLyog which is updated regularly.

[Update] - Just downloaded and installed [NaviCat 8](https://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat-for-mysql) for MySQL and was not impressed

After I added this post I reviewed and downloaded v8 of NaviCat for MySQL. In comparison with user interface of SQLyog there is no comparison. SQLyog is better and more intuitive. Especially with the two latest features mentioned earlier. Immediately I noticed how SQLyog keeps you in one window when trying to view the data of a table, while Navicat spawns a new window. The report builder and viewer is the only thing that would put Navicat above SQLyog IMHO, and I already have other means to handle reports using ASP.NET. Try both products and I think you'll agree with me.

[image]

Comment: Appreciate this is a very old post but for posterity, the SQLyog Community Edition no longer provides the "Database Synchronization Wizard" feature - selecting it from the Powertools menu brings up a message it is "available in ENTERPRISE/ULTIMATE version" (i.e. paid versions). Not sure if/when this changed.

Answer (score 3):

although i dont have any experience with it, i hear that navicat would be the tool to use:

[https://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat-for-mysql](http://mysql.navicat.com/)

also toad for mysql i hear isnt bad:

http://www.quest.com/toad-for-mysql/

Comment: navicate site is not loading. Bye bye

Answer (score 1):

[Toad for MySQL](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/toad-for-mysql-80/) can do both a "Schema Compare" as well as a "Data Compare" (and a lot more).

It used to be freeware, but the [latest versions](http://toadformysql.com/index.jspa) are not. [You can still find the old versions though](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/toad-for-mysql-80/).

Comment: No longer free in 2018 :(

Comment: @HPWD yes it looks like the latest version has changed. But you can still find the older version https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/toad-for-mysql-80/

Comment: Is there a version number you can recommend I look for?

Comment: @HPWD Version 8.* should work

Comment: Ugg, I just realized the link you provided is for Version 8. :facepalm:

Answer (score 0):

I've used Navicat for more than 3 years. It provides all the features that I need and save me tons of time for managing and developing MySQL and Oracle.

You can find a visual tutorial about Navicat's data/ structure synchronization at http://support.navicat.com/visual_tutorial/data_sync.html.