# MySQL Database synchronization

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database, synchronization

Is there any free MySQL synchronization tool out there?

I need to synchronize the database structure across servers. Data synchronization is not necessary (but is a plus).

It needs to be free (for non commercial use), not a free trial.

**Edit:**
None of the answers so far has worked, were free, or a suitable to my needs.

Comment: I presume replication isn't an option?

Comment: replication may be more than he needs, seems he needs to set up 2 server side appilcations to send the data in chunks until its complete, another way is to FTP The database VIA php with time out set at 0.

Comment: What requirements beyond free do you have?  syncronous or asyncronous?

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52583/best-tool-for-synchronizing-mysql-databases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Toad® for MySQL](http://toadformysql.com/index.jspa) can do both a "Schema Compare" as well as a "Data Compare" (and a lot more).

By the way: the software is freeware - in case somebody asks.

Answer (score 0):

The only application i know that does this is Navicat for Mysql. It is fairly cheap, however it is not free :(

Answer (score 0):

try with mysql replication (part of the mysql solution) if still isnt a option. you can make a script which send a "show create table" for each table and store the structure and replicate it in the new server(s)

Comment: echo 'show tables' | mysql mysql -ppassword -N | awk '{print "echo show create table " $1 "| mysql mysql -ppassword -N -E" }'  | sh #change the database name from "mysql" and in the output remove the first two lines of earch table. and you get a file with the structure, also change the password

Answer (score 0):

There is a free tool that does this, it's called Mysql Workbench and they have a mac version. You need to reverse engineer your schema before synching..

Answer (score 0):

Try [Daffodil Replicator](http://opensource.replicator.daffodilsw.com/), it is available in Open Source version as well. It is a Java tool for data synchronization, data migration, and data backup between various database servers.