# How to sync local database and server with PHP&MYSQL webapp

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications

I have a web application in PHP & MySQL.

It has three local systems connected with one database server.
Each local system has a primary computer which has the source code connected directly to database server. Other computers connect to each primary computer to use the application.

The problem is:
When the connection drops between one of these systems and the database server, the application can store data in the local system database. When the connection comes back up again, I want the local database changes to the synchronized with the remote database.

How can I do this?

Comment: Try to work with session, this will help you for what you want to do.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: maybe a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722659/online-offline-database-synchronization-mysql-php)

Comment: thank Joe. That help me very much.

Comment: are you get solution