# Automated MySQL DB backup and restore on local server

Tags: mysql, database, backup, restore

I have several websites on several hosting packages utilizing several MySQL DBs. What I want is to get daily instances of ALL these databases and restore them on a local server. So I will have all my databases locally updated from the online ones. 
Which is the best way to achieve this. 
Thank you.

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722659/online-offline-database-synchronization-mysql-php/18780493#18780493

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What I actually need is not db sychronization, but a daily dumping of all databases of several hosts into a local server and then restoring these databases there, overwriting the existing.

Comment: SQLyog can do that. You can save and schedule it according to your time intervals.

Comment: Yeah it says so, I was hoping for a not-payed solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue.  My plan is to automate fetching the database backup from a sftp location and then restoring the database in the next location.  There are probably several intermediate steps to make sure this happens, like drop database if exists, etc.  But I think it will work.  I, like you, don't need database synchronisation.  My purposes are for data warehousing.  The external database is from an external vendor who is willing to share database dumps with me weekly.

Hope that helps, your question is quite old now. :)