# Mysql database sync between two databases

Tags: mysql, database

We are running a Java PoS (Point of Sale) application at various shops, with a MySql backend. I want to keep the databases in the shops synchronised with a database on a host server.

When some changes happen in a shop, they should get updated on the host server. How do I achieve this?

Comment: mysql replication: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html

Comment: Is it easy to do it ?? how long do u think it will take ??

Comment: @peedee MySQL replication is pretty easy to set up. A few commands and an initial sync. Took me about 30 minutes my first time.

Comment: spot on good question was wondering the same thing for the same purpose]

Comment: You can either use MySQL replication feature or there are some tools available which does database synchronization, they are listed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52583/best-tool-for-synchronizing-mysql-databases

Comment: To sync the databases they must have the same definition and then data can be synced. You can try SQLyog, MySQL Workbench,etc. that could do help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on dba.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Replication is not very hard to create.

Here's some good tutorials:

http://www.ghacks.net/2009/04/09/set-up-mysql-database-replication/

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-howto.html

http://www.lassosoft.com/Beginners-Guide-to-MySQL-Replication

Here some simple rules you will have to keep in mind (there's more of course but that is the main concept):

1. Setup 1 server (master) for writing data.
2. Setup 1 or more servers (slaves) for reading data.

This way, you will avoid errors.

*For example:*
If your script insert into the same tables on both master and slave, you will have duplicate primary key conflict.

You can view the "slave" as a "backup" server which hold the same information as the master but cannot add data directly, only follow what the master server instructions.

*NOTE: Of course you can read from the master and you can write to the slave but make sure you don't write to the same tables (master to slave and slave to master).*

I would recommend to monitor your servers to make sure everything is fine.

Let me know if you need additional help

Comment: Yes, Shop = master, Server = slave

Comment: I have configured the master one now and i am going to connect to one slave database .. when i do this, any changes to the master will reflect in the slave and will changes in the slave reflect to the master as well ??

Comment: yes right away if the setup is good! you can insert a record in the master and do a select in the slave to test. if that pass, you are set!

Comment: Hey mate ... I have got error 1045 on the slave . what would be the reason for it ? you have any idea ?

Comment: ERROR 1045: Access denied for user: 'root@localhost' (Using password: NO) and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/access-denied.html

Comment: Hi i have done successfully for a single master to slave replication, thanks a lot for your help @BookOfZeus .. Now how do i monitor it do you know any tools because it should not bring down the performance of the front-end application.

Comment: Nice! congrats. the easy monitor you can do is when you log to the master you type: `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G` then look for any "error", if you have 0 or empty, you are set!

Comment: ok thanks its all fine .. no errors .. but will the performance of the server go down when there are huge amount of transactions going on various databases ?

Comment: performance on which server slave? master? is it a network performance? when you do show slave status, how many seconds the slave is behind the server?

Comment: hi @BookOfZeus sorry for de late reply .. i have tested it for a while .. the application is working fine now , the master and slave are perfectly in sync and its not running behind.. Thanks a lot mate ..

Comment: My own scenario entails having several masters [databases in different locations] and one slave [online database]. Will this solution work? Is it even possible? Thanks in advance for responding - @BookOfZeus

Answer (score 23):

three different approaches:

1. Classic client/server approach:  don't put any database in the shops; simply have the applications access your server.  Of course it's better if you set a VPN, but simply wrapping the connection in SSL or ssh is reasonable.  Pro: it's the way databases were originally thought.  Con: if you have high latency, complex operations could get slow, you might have to use stored procedures to reduce the number of round trips.
2. replicated master/master: as @Book Of Zeus suggested.  Cons: somewhat more complex to setup (especially if you have several shops), breaking in any shop machine could potentially compromise the whole system.  Pros: better responsivity as read operations are totally local and write operations are propagated asynchronously.
3. offline operations + sync step: do all work locally and from time to time (might be once an hour, daily, weekly, whatever) write a summary with all new/modified records from the last sync operation and send to the server.  Pros: can work without network, fast, easy to check (if the summary is readable).  Cons: you don't have real-time information.

Comment: I have requirement to setup 3rd type of db sync (offline operations + sync), would love to read more on this. Not able to google this one out. Is their a book/article i can refer to ?

Answer (score 11):

SymmetricDS is the answer. It supports multiple subscribers with one direction or bi-directional asynchronous data replication. It uses web and database technologies to replicate tables between relational databases, in near real time if desired.

Comprehensive and robust Java API to suit your needs.

Comment: if i have internal server with separate db to by on some area with no internet , and i have online buyers on database web hosted and i want to migrate the internal database buys into live , can you please advise what will happen to auto increments between two if they both were reserving same id it will be messy right !? so ( i need to sync operations made on internal db into live without affecting the ids auto incremeant and relations between tables)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Schema and Data Comparison tools](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/database-synchronization.html) in dbForge Studio for MySQL. These tool will help you to compare, to see the differences, generate a synchronization script and synchronize two databases.