# How do I sync 2 MySQL databases?

Tags: mysql, database, synchronization, multiple-databases

I written a program to work with a MySQL database that powers my website and I have recently bought some reseller hosting however the hosting company has restricted external access on the shared server, so I was going to setup an external mySQL database on another server that can be accessed remotely, however to do this I need a PHP file on my reseller server that can connect to the local database and the remote database and sync them on request from the application via a url.

Does anyone know the best method achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql database sync between two databases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707859/mysql-database-sync-between-two-databases)

Comment: Replication: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html

Answer (score 4):

Try using [SQLyog's Database synchronization tool](http://www.webyog.com)

[image]

Comment: You can sync only 2 databases at a time.

Comment: So, what should I use to sync more than 2 databases?

Comment: Replication is only passive, not active, right? The slave databases will be sync to the master database changes but slaves will not be automatically sync back to master, right? So, write to master and read from slave ?

Comment: You can check SymmetricDS www.symmetricds.org.