# How to set up two MySQL databases on separate servers to sync with string replace?

Tags: mysql, string, replace, synchronization

I have two **MySQL databases on two separate servers**. Both will host the same CMS but **one will serve general visitor traffic** while the other - the master - is accessed by editors. The **contents of the the two database have to be identical**, but as the two servers have different domain names, every **sync should perform a string replace**: from domain A, to domain B.

I found a MySQL replication is possible, but how can one sync two databases with a specific string to be always replaced to another specific string?

**Update:**
As an example:

```
//Preset string to search:
"apple"

//Replacement string:
"orange"

//Edited data:
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit apple amet"

//Data sent to sync with other server:
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit orange amet"
```

Comment: Hey i think this allready solved here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946540/how-do-i-sync-2-mysql-databases

Comment: "I have found that a MySQL replication is possible, but how can one sync two databases with a specific string to be always replaced to another specific string?"- with this I mean that if the contents of DB A is "something something apple something" then DB B would be synced to "something something orange something"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to use replication as to avoid using a Service for populating x number of databases, you need to identify if it's possible to write mysql triggers for data inserts/updates on replicated databases. I will assume it's possible.

If so, you would write triggers for Insert and Update operations on replicated database. When triggered is activated, you would run a procedure, which would run string replace as you please on incoming data, changing the data, and pass it onto the replicated database.

So lets say you have database A (master) and B (replicated). Inserting data "something something apple something" into db A, would replicate the data onto db B. At this point, and again - I only assume, a trigger can be activated upon "Insert" operation on db B - allowing you to edit data that will be inserted into db B. Inside of the trigger you could call a procedure, which would do string replace as needed, and pass the data onto db B.