# How to synchronize MySQL databases that runs locally?

Tags: mysql, localhost, synchronize

I'm working on a web application (based on PHP & MySQL). I work on 2 PC locally.PC's are not part of network.
is there an easy way to synchronize data bases over internet?
My application runs locally using Apache server.

Comment: You want to synchronize databases over the internet from PCs that aren't part of a network? How _are_ they connected?

Comment: they are not connected together and they are in different places but they both have access to the internet.

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707859/mysql-database-sync-between-two-databases