# How to synchronize local database with a server in java application

Tags: java, mysql, database, synchronization, replication

I want to add the feature of database synchronization to my project. It should be like this. when the internet connection is available the application should transact with the online database server and when the internet connection is not available it should keep track of the transactions and should update the online db server when connection is available. how can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some answers in this question [Mysql database sync between two databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707859/mysql-database-sync-between-two-databases)

But one of the elements which is very important is data consistency if you have multiple "offline" databases. For example, if you have 2 users working in their own offline database and they perform an update on the same record and you are going to synchronize: how are you going to solve this problem ? Typically a lot of the database internal code is about record locking etc... to avoid such problems.

Comment: yes GerritCap. such things are possible. But here i was looking for some implementation examples. Thanks.