# Generating Update Query

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have two identical mysql database running on different machine. My problem is that I have to update few column values of a table from one db to other. Can I generate update query for particular column in phpmyadmin or whats the other way to generate update query so that I can run same query on other machine and have values in sync.

**For example:**

Machine1 employee table has salary column. I want to get the update query for salary column based on primary key of employee table. e.g.

```
update employee  set salary = 5000 where id = 1; 
update employee  set salary = 5200 where id = 2; 
...
...................................where id = 1000;
```

Comment: Shodunt you use replication for this stuff?

Comment: Ya that's doable, but I have to first truncate the table then reload all the data every time. I was trying if we can simply generate update queries for a particular column. Your suggestion will work if I don't get any correct answer :)

Comment: Try to use compound trigger in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understood your question.
If you need to change something in different database you just need to connect to other databse first.

So:

- Connect to db1
- Update something in db1
- Connect db2
- Update something in db2

Additionally you can use transaction to avoid problems where one db will be updated and the other one will fail.

If you can't save to db1 and db2 in the same time, you can sync two db: [Mysql database sync between two databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707859/mysql-database-sync-between-two-databases)

Comment: No sorry, I think I didn't summarized the question correctly. I just simply want to download the update query for a particular column for each row with primary key in where clause. So that I can run that query on other machines which have same database and table.

Comment: I just want to keep two different db's in sync. They are on different machines.

Comment: Do you just want to sync db2 with db1?
If yes please take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707859/mysql-database-sync-between-two-databases