# Synchronize remote Mysql database to local in C# GUI Application

Tags: c#, php, mysql, database, winforms

I'm implementing an application to sync data from a remote mysql server to local mysql database. Without the main part (Synchronization) I have almost done with the application.

I want to know how to synchronize my local mysql database from a remote mysql database. I'm ok if it want to run from PHP scrip. but, if it runs from PHP script I want to know how to call php script from C# application. So the application can call php and sync at a certain time. Apologize if my question is unclear to you.

Any help on this would be great.

Thanks in Advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you cant setup master -slave replication with your local database. Here is more information. 
Here is good starting point.
[Mysql database sync between two databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707859/mysql-database-sync-between-two-databases)

Comment: @Ajey Appreciate you support. I want to know is it possible to implement with C# winform application. Anyhow I want to use the sync with my C# gui application.