# How to Sync 2 mysql databases with the same schema using yii2 or php

Tags: php, mysql, synchronization, yii2, database-replication

I have an application developed in yii2 that it is hosted online and the same application hosted in an intranet because is not access to internet in this location.

The application it is very simple basicaly 2 tables customers and attendance.
How can I sync off line database with the online once they finish to work.

I use to do this in vb adding a field with the change status and then comparing the records one by one.
I wonder if it is a better way to do that in yii2 or php.

Comment: Please don't add "thanks" and your name to the question. It's redundant information.

Comment: Sync in one or both directions? This could probably be realized without php/yii since db syncing is a general topic.

Comment: it is allays in one direction because they will use the systems one at a time

Comment: You may want to look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707859/mysql-database-sync-between-two-databases . I don't how professional, secure and stable it should be.

Comment: Look for "master - slave MySql replication"

Comment: Or you can write simple Yii script: add timestamp field (on update), select new rows from one table, update/insert new rows to another table.