# What would be best way to synchronizate two databases, other in LAN and another in public internet

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications

I got server in our local area network that is running mysql and apache services. It's blocked from public internet, so you can't access those services anywhere outside our lan. I'm running an application written by me on that server. Now seems that we would need ligther version of that application to run in our public website. Public website has also mysql database service installed. So my question would be, how to sync these databases. Basically all i need some way to secure that all entries have their own unique id.

Comment: Replication over VPN?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707859/mysql-database-sync-between-two-databases