# Maintain communication between two servers php, websocket and socket.io

Tags: php, websocket, socket.io

I have two servers. A and B. A has access to the internet, but does not have public IP. B has internet access, and has public IP.

In PHP, I create a file inside A, and to fetch information from B, I call file_get_contents, which checks if there is a change in the mysql table in B. If there are new records, it fetches the contents. A picked up contents of B.

To send content to B, I created another file in A, and I use file_post_content to send new records from A to B. A sent content to B.

I set the crontab to run every hour, and call the above functions.

Using websocket, socket.io, could you do this instantly? When there are new records in the mysql table of B, the records are copied to the database in A. And when there are new records in A, copy to B, instantly.

Comment: Yes, you could do that with websockets.

Comment: If all you're doing is keeping two databases in sync, you could use [mysql's replication features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707859/mysql-database-sync-between-two-databases) to do that.

Comment: As @JayBlanchard said you could do this with websockets, but you still need a trigger to know when to push the info from A to B so this wouldn't  eliminate the need for crontab. I don't really see an advantage of using websockets for this purpose, as you need to maintain the connection and handle disconnections, etc.

Easiest way to handle this in your application I think is to run your POST function once you finish updating the database if you have control over that.  Then you get rid of cron, and just have two functions.

Comment: Hi. The database is just an example. I would use websocket yes.

Comment: For example: server A collects various data via SNMP from the devices connected to the network of which it is part, and would like to display this data in real time, in graphics, hosted on server B