# Compare MySQL Database tables / field structure and Stored Procedures

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database in the dev environment that I change on a regularly.
Then when I'm done I want to synchronize the tables/fields/Stored Procedures, not the records.

I'm looking for a tool with a nice interface where I can connect to dev on one side and prod on the other side, then I click "show difference" and I see them.

Furthermore, there's another button that will sync both databases

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: [MySQL Work Bench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) is a great tool for exporting database syntax as you go. I've never had to connect to more than one environment so I don't know how that works. What do you mean by "sync both databases"?

Comment: I'm adding a field in the dev database, I'm changing the format of a field, I'm adding an index, I'm changing three Stored Procedures, etc... When I'm done, I want all the changes to be implemented in the prod database. I can do it manually but I have to make sure I did not forget anything. I'd like a tool that would compare the database and apply the change. A bit something like beyondcompare

Comment: [Check out the answers to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52583/best-tool-for-synchronizing-mysql-databases)

Comment: I found my own answer, mysql compare http://www.red-gate.com/products/mysql/mysql-compare/    I tried it, it could not work better. What a great product !!!!

Comment: glad you found something!