# How to use SVN by multiple developers while keeping database schema changes in sync?

Tags: mysql, svn, tortoisesvn, mariadb

We have a couple of developers working on an web app and are using SVN for the repo (we are using tortoiseSVN locally). We each maintain a copy of the database locally. When we commit and then update the staging server with the latest changes, almost without fail Maria (MySQL) will not restart. We'll have to delete log files and jump through hoops to get Maria restarted. There has to be a better process and I could use some guidance on getting to this better place. We are not 100% sure which files should be ignored which may be all the problem is

I found the following SO answers but I they don't quite address my question:
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/65351/sync-two-mysql-databases-in-two-different-locations
- [Best tool for synchronizing MySQL databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52583/best-tool-for-synchronizing-mysql-databases)

I don't *feel* like this is a syncing issue of databases but since I've not done this before with MySQL so my exception may need some adjustment.

The ideal scenario would work like this (some steps are skipped for the sake of brevity):

1. SVN stores the master database
2. Developer SVN Commits their changes
3. Using Remote Desktop, connect  to Staging Server
4. Stop Maria
5. SVN Update the staging server (I see this almost like it's a 3rd developer without commit privileges)
6. start Maria
7. View web application and test changes

The server is Windows 2008 R2
Web Server is Lucee/Tomcat/IIS
Database is Maria 5.x

In a case like this, is mysqldump going to be the most efficient way to go here?

Comment: Database is relatively small right now but long term, it will grow of course so dumping isn't going to be a viable solution long term.

Comment: I should also add that it really is the schema I need to keep in sync right now more so than the contents.

Comment: Found a lead... Looking into MySQL Workbench (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-design-schema.html)