# How do you track database changes?

Tags: mysql, database

Is there any tool that can compare the development database and the public database?

Comment: You may find these useful - http://stackoverflow.com/q/1607/569659 - http://stackoverflow.com/q/6371/569659 - http://stackoverflow.com/q/4952/569659 - http://stackoverflow.com/q/175451/569659

Comment: If you want to compare content too, you can use the checksum function: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/checksum-table.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Navicat for MySQL.

Answer (score 3):

Redgate software have a schema comparison tool called [MySQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/mysql-compare/), which I have used to great effect before. When we had an issue with our databases getting out of sync. It is in early access/beta so it is currently free.

Unfortunately it is Windows only and I have not tried it under Wine on linux.

Answer (score 0):

Redgate Software bundle has both data and schema compare. I've been using them happily without looking back.

PS: It is for SQL Server only though...

Comment: Red Gate also has Oracle and MySQL comparison tools.