# How do you make changes to a production MySQL database?

Tags: mysql

I'm still fairly new to MySQL, and have an app which uses a MySQL database. What is the proper workflow for copying changes from a development copy to the production DB (indexes, new fields, etc)? So far, I've just used phpMyAdmin to make the changes one at a time, but it seems wrong to work this way.

Comment: That is indeed the wrong way. The right way is to create a change script/process - hopefully with automated tooling - and then apply it. If the changes are *all* done this way from the *same reference* then it is a relatively trivial forward-process without schema issues (because any such issues are pre-resolved when generating the script). Use a *staging* database that can be used to test-apply the change script before an attempt is made to apply it to production. This staging database should also be used during other parts of the test-before-release cycle. (And make sure to have backups..)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you manage databases in development, test, and production?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6371/how-do-you-manage-databases-in-development-test-and-production)